# Devise Custom Update Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for my authentication/registration. I have an edit user page, which devise has generated for me that looks like this:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

The issue is that my "user" has more fields than devise has generated for me, and I want to pass those in as well as handle various scenarios created by user actions on the front end. Basically, I need to customize whatever Devise is doing behind the scenes when I click "Update" to submit the form.

How could I either override the Devise controller to implement what I need, or have the submit button route to a different update controller that has the actions I need?

Here are my routes (brokers and renters are both a type of user, synonymous for these purposes):

devise_for :brokers
devise_for :renters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override a Devise controller by declaring your custom registrations controller as a subclass of `Devise::RegistrationsController`:

```
# app/controllers/authentication/registrations_controller.rb
class Authentication::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    # custom logic
    super
  end

end
```

Then, define routes to your custom controller in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :brokers, :controllers => { :registrations => "authentication/registrations" }
devise_for :renters, :controllers => { :registrations => "authentication/registrations" }
```

Comment: I'm trying this for my update but it doesn't seem to be directing to the right controller. Does this work for PUT requests?

Comment: I had a small typo, give my updated routes a try. Yes, this should work for all RESTful routes, including ones using the PUT method (i.e., update).